# In which episode did Joffrey force a man to put his arm on a hot pot?

Tags: game-of-thrones, episode-identification

Which episode of "Game of Thrones" includes a scene where Joffrey forces a man to put his arm on a hot pot?

I know it's stupid, but I'm almost sure that such scene was in there. However I can't find any reference to it.

Could anyone help me? I mean point out the right episode, or deny its existence?

Comment: The phrase "to a hot pot" (from before the question was edited for language) is too vague. If you remember such a scene, describe more detail. Is this a cooking pot? Were they in someone's house, or in the castle?

Comment: In my fevered dreams after watching Game of Thrones until 5am, the scene does exist, and the OP meant [Betty’s hotpot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betty_Williams_(Coronation_Street)#Betty.27s_hotpot). Betty would have sorted Joffrey out in about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’ve recently watched seasons 1–3, and I can’t remember a scene where Joffrey directly uses heat to torment someone — although I might have missed it.

There are a few scenes that are *kind of* similar:

1. In *A Golden Crown* (season 1, episode 6), Viserys demands that Khal Drogo deliver what he promised. In response,

   > Kkal Drogo melts some gold in [what must have been a very hot pot](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5849/can-you-melt-gold-in-a-regular-campfire), and pours it over Viserys’ head.

   This takes place across the Narrow Sea, however, so Joffrey isn’t involved at all.
2. In *Baelor* (season 1, episode 9), Tyrion and Shae play a game in his tent where they balance a lit candle on their arm, and see who can bear the pain for the longest.

   Again, Joffrey isn’t involved, but it’s the only scene I can remember featuring arms being exposed to heat.
3. In *Fire and Blood* (season 1, episode 10), a bard who sung a bawdy song about

   > King Robert’s death

   was asked by Joffrey whether he would rather keep his fingers or his tongue. He chose his fingers, so Jeoffrey ordered the Hound to tongue cut out. Before doing so, the Hound heated his knife in a fire.
4. In *The North Remembers* (season 2, episode 1), the City Watch (on the orders of Joffrey, although he’s not present) holds a blacksmith’s face near to his fire, while trying to discover the location of Gendry.

Comment: So this scene if not probably from 'Game of Thrones'. I wonder then which movie includes that. However thanks. :)

Comment: @xliiv You can ask a new question about that ;).

Comment: @TGar thanks for your suggestion but i gave it up

Comment: Sometimes, you’ve just got to let these things go.